# How to identify those string without English alphabet, numbers and "_" and replace the rest?

Tags: r, regex

I have the the following data

```
s <- c("コハニー", "Cat", "Blue", "زبان","D-1")
```

And I wish to exclude those data that are not in English alphabet and replace them with something like "ABC". So my **ideal output** is

```
"ABC"  "Cat"  "Blue" "ABC"  "D-1"
```

I used the following code but it can not recognise  `_`  and `-`. How can I clarify  `_` and `-` in Regex?

```
s[!grepl('^[A-Za-z0-9_]+$', s)] <- 'ABC'
```

This gives me:

```
ABC"  "Cat"  "Blue" "ABC"  "ABC"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add `-` and `_` at the end, so it should be `'^[A-Za-z0-9_-]+$`

I always find [regexr.com](http://regexr.com/) to be really helpful for testing out these problems and learning more about regular expressions.

```r
s <- c("????", "Cat", "Blue", "????","D-1")

s[!grepl('^[A-Za-z0-9\\_\\-]+$', s)] <- 'ABC'

s
#> [1] "ABC"  "Cat"  "Blue" "ABC"  "D-1"
```

Comment: Minor note: in some cases, you don't need to double \ escape the - and the _ like here: s[!grepl('^[[:alnum:]_-]+$', s)] <- ''

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize that. Just updated the answer

Comment: Would have added "[[:punct:]] to keep all ASCII punctuation.

Answer (score 3):

For readability, I suggest using [:alnum:] to catch the alphanumeric characters, followed by the explicit non-alphanumeric characters you want to keep (e.g. "_-"), like this:

```
s <- c("コハニー", "Cat", "Blue", "زبان","D-1")
s[!grepl('^[[:alnum:]_-]+$', s)] <- ''
s
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add `_` and `-` directly in your character class (without escaping). Hyphen `-` doesn't need to be escaped if its the first or last character in the class i.e

```
[A-Za-z0-9_-]
```

So you can try this:

```
s[!grepl('^[A-Za-z0-9_-]+$', s)] <- 'ABC'
```

Take a look at this [R Demo](http://ideone.com/EzH8J4)